# progress bar for existing php image upload script?

Tags: php, jquery, progress-bar, image-uploading

I currently have a PHP script I use to upload image files but I'm trying to find or create a simple jquery progress bar for the upload.

Does anyone know of a script I could use to do this? I don't want to replace my entire upload mechanism because it works really well.  I just want to display the upload status to the user.

Any suggestions on how I might be able to get the current status from PHP and pass it off to jquery?

Comment: Just FYI, the majority of these scripts use flash to perform the upload since the nature of HTTP is request/response. The flash objects allow the developer to tell how much of the file has been uploaded. It's not really what you'd expect: some sort of callback from PHP.

Comment: I was hoping for some sort of callback from PHP so I could create the jquery progress bar myself.  I really want to avoid flash because many of my users are on apple products where flash isn't supported.

Comment: If they're on iOS, they aren't able to upload files anyway so the flash uploader won't be an issue. If you needed to implement a progress bar that isn't related to file uploads, jQTouch has one: http://jqtouch.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar is a simple solution.

It doesn't require flash which is always good!

If i'm correct, however, you can't upload files from Apple mobile devices.

Comment: That's a clever solution, using the APC api. I've never seen that before. One note however, the way they're handling that file upload is dangerous. Be sure to review the file upload security docs: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 1):

See
http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/